# how to echo table and data in json array?

Tags: php, json

How to echo table and data in json array ?
I have problem here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdDuS.jpg)

```
$return_arr = array();
$row_array['itemnol']= "[SUKSES] Data Berhasil Ditambahkan";

$row_array['itemsatu']= //i want displaysome data here from my query with table forma";
array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );

echo json_encode($return_arr,true);
```

I can not write table html in my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of screen shot, Update the code in your post.

Answer (score -1):

You can do in two ways:

**First:**

1. base64 encode for HTML string
2. json encode

   ```
   $html = "Random HTML String"; //Use addslashes if problem creating string
   $encoded_html = json_encode(base64_encode($html));
   ```

When Retriving back

3. json decode
4. base64 decode

   $decoded_html = base64_decode(json_decode($encoded_html));

**Second:**

Just Key and Value pair would work.

```
{"htmlstring" => "Some html string"} //use addslashes if issue creating string.
```